# Vue js / Nodejs Java Script export docx files

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2

Hi I have a requirement that user should be able to fill some forms from the front-end UI and export that to a docx file. So that he/ she can further edit / customize that file and also this docx file should be a predefined template file as well.

I did export to pdfs from front end and saw that people export csv files from front end. But is it possible to export docx files in front end?

In this project's front-end is a Vuejs single page app and the back-end is a Node.js Restapi. So either front-end or back-end I need to do this.

Is this possible in Java script?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx

Comment: @Jaybird thanks a lot. Have you used this package personally?